# Как правильно написать функцию в телеграм-боте, которая отправляет фото

Tags: python, telebot

телеграм-бот отправляет фото, если видит в чате слово фото

Я сделал:

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def send_foto(message):
    if message.text == "фото":
        photo = open('foto.jpg', 'rb')
        client.send_photo(chatId, photo)
```

не работает :(

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['photo'])
def send_photo_to_chat(message):
     client.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo = url_photo, caption = 'caption_text')
```

Comment: caption - это необязательный параметр?

Comment: что делать, если я хочу отправить уже заготовленную фотографию (которая лежит в папке с программой) ,  а не ссылку на фото?)

Comment: caption - это параметр на который будет реагировать бот? в данном случае на слово 'фото' , если я напишу caption = 'фото'

Comment: caption - это подпись к фото. Обычно подпись пишет пользователь и отправляет фото, в этот параметр можно передавать свой текст, или получать от пользователя. Насчет заготовленной фотографии вам нужно обращаться к файлам через питон. сыль: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html

Comment: и да caption обязательный параметр в том случае если фото с подписью! Иначе вы будете отправлять только фото. К примеру я пользователь отправил фото с caption = 'На этом фото я программирую', то соответственно эту запись я так же должен передавать в сообщение. Ещё один нюанс, если подписи нет, но caption обрабатывается вы можете столкнуться с несоответствием типов, советую содержимое caption всегда переводить в str() -> info_caption = str(message.caption)